# $\overline{\operatorname{int}(A)} \subseteq A$ for all closed sets $A \subseteq \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Is $\overline{\operatorname{int}(A)}$ (the closure of the interior of $A$) contained in $A$ for all closed sets $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ true? How can I prove it?

Comment: What is the question? $\overline{int(A)}$ for closed $A$ is ......?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true.

We have $\operatorname{int}(A)\subset A$ for any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Now use the fact that $C\subset D \implies \overline {C}\subset \overline {D}$. You get $\overline{\operatorname{int}(A)}\subset \overline A$.

But $\overline A=A$ ($\because A$ is closed). Therefore, $\overline{\operatorname{int}(A)}\subset A$

Note: $C\subset D \implies \overline C \subset \overline D$ To prove this fact use the definition of closure as: The closure of a subset C is the smallest subset containing C.

Comment: I got your idea. But how can I show that $C \subset D$ leads to $\bar C \subset \bar D$?

Comment: Use the definition of the closure as the intersection of all closed sets that contain the given set,  it follows directly from that

Comment: I see... Thanks!